# Using beforeunload to execute task before page exit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

**I'm trying to get an action executed before page leave, this requires a GET request being executed.**

I would like to give the GET request at least **50-100ms** in order to get the request forwarded to the web server.

I'm capturing the `beforeunload` action using:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    send_data();
});
```

---

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the highest chance to get your request sent if you make it synchronous (`async: false` in the `$.ajax()` options if you are using jQuery).

But you cannot be sure it always gets through..

Comment: +1 Yes, this is one of the few good uses of synchronous AJAX requests.

Comment: thanks for that! I'm having problems in IE making ajax calls to another domain unfortunately :|

Answer (score -1):

You should prevent default action with event.preventDefault().

Note that not every browser support beforeunload

Comment: He doesn't want to stop the user from navigating away (which is not possible anyway. onbeforeunload has to return a string which is then used in a confirmation window generated by the browser)

Comment: It is possible, I have seen annoying examples

Comment: It isn't; the only way to "prevent" users from leaving completely is by using hacks like infinite loops of `alert()`.